# Is my oscilloscope working or not?

Tags: oscilloscope

I bought today a very old second hand oscilloscope (Philips PM 3253), see picture below.[image]

I put the probe into a +5v circuit before a LED inside an Arduino breadboard (and checked with a multimeter +5v was on that circuit).

However, whatever knobs I turn or switches on the oscilloscope I set, the horizontal line always stays in the middle (except when I change the position knob on the bottom left).

It's my first-ever oscilloscope ... what switch/knob should I set to get a reading of +5v ... or is the oscilloscope broken?

@Update: It works now (sort of). I noticed there was a multiplication of 10 switch on the probe itself (so the difference between 0 and +5v was not visible), and had to change the main amplitude knob and the inner knob (whatever it means) and also the 0 X B Bal knob ...

But the most important is, that it works, now I have to learn what all knobs mean :-)

I made a new question, since I got some major problems using it:
[Oscilloscope makes my mains (fuse box) group go down](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/301990/oscilloscope-makes-my-mains-fuse-box-group-go-down) (maybe problem solved)

Comment: fwiw, it's very encouraging that something comes up at all, you probably just need to dial it in correctly. you have a fun afternoon ahead of you. congrats on the equipment acquisition. btw, you have it ac coupling in the photo, but you want to measure DC...

Comment: Make sure you have a common ground.

Comment: What a beauty you got there!

Comment: @Stark: I used the same ground as my Arduino breadboard

Comment: It appears to be an old analog **storage

Comment: @True it was offered as a 'memory' scope, have to find out exactly how to use all options.

Comment: Appears to be an old analog **storage 'scope**. Your photo looks to have the whole screen stored. Play with the persistence knob to keep from flooding the screen with green background. Hope you can find some info on how analog storage works - it is a very neat feature.

Comment: I searched google and found [this](http://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/looking-for-service-manual-philips-pm3253-or-pm3251.126106/) with a [link to a German language manual](http://www.download-service-manuals.com/en/manual.php?file=Philips-2183.pdf)

Comment: @glen_geek  I tried to, but I cannot use the scope for more than 10 minutes without having the house fux box group down :-(

Comment: Sounds like you could use a manual for this scope.  The good news is that older scopes tended to come with a complete set of circuit diagrams so that you could maintain them.  That might lead you through some basic operations and possible help work out what is tripping our fuse. I have no "How to use an oscilloscope" primers to suggest but a quick search throws up some options.  Is it as simple as the house circuit being overloaded?

Comment: @TafT (and others) ... I found a manual (well very similar to mine). Also I think I found the problem, but need to do a continuous test (like keeping it on for an hour).

Comment: Re: Your update. The x10 switch on the probe is there for a reason. Attaching the probe to a signal will have an impact on the signal you are measuring. Putting the probe in x10 mode drops the signal by a factor of 10 but also reduces this impact. Newer digital scopes will have an option to multiply everything by 10 so you don't need to worry about that, on your scope just turn the scale up by a factor of 10 and do the maths in your head. And as has been said, DC not AC to see a constant voltage. AC removes any constant voltage offset.

Comment: @Andrew thanks for that insight, today I also want to play a bit with all knobs and check how to read the display results as a consequence. Your info about the x10 switch will help, thank you!

Comment: Does the **PERSIST** knob "click" when you rotate fully CCW? looks like its not-quite-there. That may help turn down the screen-flooding background. Nice reasonably-fast 'scope..

Comment: @glen_geek yes it works, but than the screen does not change (maybe that's the store option)... I should read what it is actually good for. But what's more intriguing, the scope still seems to work. I hope also after a few hours. When I tried yesterday after a few hours every half an hour the complete main fuse (of the house) was turned off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try moving the switch above your probe to DC

Comment: Just tried, but no difference, see update in 1 minute

Comment: Well it certainly needs to be in DC mode. What happens when you turn the amplitude knob to the left of your probe

Comment: That did the trick (+ the inner knob and the O X B Bal knob).

Answer (score 5):

See that BNC connector on the left, labeled "Cal."? "Cal." is short for "Calibration". Stick the tip of your probe into that (thanks to Peter Bennet for this clarification). It provides a square wave signal that's intended for calibrating probes. If you see the signal, the scope is working. If you don't see it, the calibration output might not be working, or the scope itself might not be working.

Comment: How should I hook that up? I mean I can connect the probe connector to it, but where should I contact the end of the probe with?

Comment: @MichelKeijzers: just stick the tip of your probe into the center contact of the BNC "Cal" connector.

Comment: I can try (but I'm afraid the fuse will go down again), it happens now even when not really changing a setting or putting the probe to anything).

Comment: @PeterBennett I got two lines when I tried, which seems like a square wave, however, whatever I tried with the Time knobs, I always got two lines, not any square wave. After 5 minutes the oscilloscopes set my house fuxe box group down (see question at end of my post above).

Comment: Set the main trigger mode to "Auto", trigger source switch to Ya or Yb, depeding on which channel your probe is in, set the main timebase to 1 mS/div, and adjust the Trigger Level to get a stable square wave display.  The scope should not cause the main fuse to trip.

Comment: Ah. They way I was taught to do this I connect the probe to my body; this picks up 60hz.

Answer (score 2):

Been a while since I've used an analogue scope but try the following:

- Connect your probe to channel B as channel A might be blown.
- You may have a trigger enabled, use the 'level' knobs on the right to make sure it is within range. It could be expecting an external trigger so test it by applying a voltage to the Trigger BNC input
- The switch at the top, move it from LF to DC.

Comment: I already got it working, now I have problems with the fusing (or lack of it), and having my house fuse box go down

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at a DC signal, you need to change the coupling mode from "AC" to "DC" (switch in the middle).

Comment: Just tried, but no difference (see update in 1 minute)